# node-sass always command not found!!! I try to everything

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

my os is macOS 10.13, and I using brew install node, actually, before brew, I install node without brew, and still not work too!

I log my install step:

```
$ npm install -g node-sass
```

//bla bla bla...done

```
$ node-sass
-bash: node-sass: command not found
```

**NOT surprisingly!** I always need set path!

```
$ npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
$ export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

then

```
$ node-sass
//Provide a Sass file to render bla bla bla ~~~
```

When I close terminal or open new terminal label, it's happen too! I still set path, AGAIN!

WHY!!! is macOS 10.13 problem?!

I even install node-saa using -g, I don't remember before macOS 10.13 is it also too!!!

cao someone tell me, why I need always set path? have other way to fix?

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the new PATH export to your `.bash_profile`.

In terminal do the following command: `open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile` (or use `nano ~/.bash_profile`, if you know how to use it).

You should see a bunch of export statements at the top of the opened file, put yours (`export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`) below them. Try reopening a new terminal window and see if `node-sass` works.